# How to transpose in SQL with column values as column headers?

Tags: sql

Is there a way to transpose values in SQL? Example

```
A    Units  Cat
Asd    4    Type1 
fsd    3    Type1 
Asd    2    Type2
gfd    5    Type2
```

Expected Output

```
A   TotalUnits  Type1      Type2
Asd   6           4           2
fsd   3           3 
gfd   5                       5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had slightly change @Lajos answer

```
select t.A,sum(t.Units) as TotalUnits,case when sum(t.T1)=0 then '' 
else cast(sum(t.T1) As varchar) end as Type1,
case when sum(t.T2)=0 then '' else cast(sum(t.T2) as varchar) end as Type2 from
(select A,
       Units,
       case
           when Cat = 'Type1' then Units
           else 0
       end as T1,
       case
           when Cat = 'Type2' then Units
           else 0
       end as T2
from yourtable) t group by t.A;
```

see demo here [Demo fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/840b9/18)

Comment: Nice answer, it's always nice to see a great answer written based on mine. Upvoted. It could have written as an edit as well.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is. If we assume that we already know what `Cat` values are, then doing this would suffice:

```
select A,
       Units,
       case
           when Cat = 'Type1' then Units
           else 0
       end as T1,
       case
           when Cat = 'Type2' then Units
           else 0
       end as T2
from yourtable;
```

The query above lacks aggregation, let's do that as well:

```
select A, sum(Units) as TotalUnits, sum(T1) as Type1, sum(T2) as Type2
from
    (select A,
           Units,
           case
               when Cat = 'Type1' then Units
               else 0
           end as Type1,
           case
               when Cat = 'Type2' then Units
               else 0
           end
    from yourtable) t;
group by A;
```

If you really want empty spaces where the sum is 0 as shown in the question, then you can use case when for the value of Type1 and Type2, respectively, in the same spirit they were initially defined.

However, you do not necessarily know what the possible values of `Cat` are. To cope with this situation you will need to load its `distinct` values and build your query dynamically.

Comment: @Always_a_learner I did not test the query. Can you point out what the problem was?

Comment: aggregation query -- not major, some column name mismatched

Comment: @Always_a_learner that's right. There was Units as TotalUnits inside the subquery, which renames Units which is referenced in the main query. Edited my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.